# Error building `LibCURL` after Pkg.add("SMTPClient") - is there a solution or an alternative?

Tags: email, julia

I attempted the installation of SMTPClient by executing in the REPL:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("SMTPClient")
```

The last line was not run successully - I got an issue from Julia:

```
Error: Error building `LibCURL`: 
│ ERROR: LoadError: Could not download https://github.com/bicycle1885/ZlibBuilder/releases/download/v1.0.4/build_Zlib.v1.2.11.jl to /home/jerzy/.julia/packages/LibCURL/lWJxD/deps/build_Zlib.v1.2.11.jl:
│ ErrorException("")
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
│  [2] #download#96(::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at /home/jerzy/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/U2dKK/src/PlatformEngines.jl:619
│  [3] download(::String, ::String) at /home/jerzy/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/U2dKK/src/PlatformEngines.jl:606
│  [4] top-level scope at /home/jerzy/.julia/packages/LibCURL/lWJxD/deps/build.jl:19
│  [5] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [6] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
│  [7] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [8] include(::String) at ./client.jl:392
│  [9] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at /home/jerzy/.julia/packages/LibCURL/lWJxD/deps/build.jl:14
│ --2020-06-14 20:26:37--  https://github.com/bicycle1885/ZlibBuilder/releases/download/v1.0.4/build_Zlib.v1.2.11.jl
│ Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.118.4
│ Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.118.4|:443... connected.
│ HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
│ Location: https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/126450947/3549c780-3c62-11e9-9144-67fac571e02a?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20200614%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200614T182643Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=fe638ea82a12f0d962d80996378f917f7d5ccd387197248e5a7ee9239f11f6d3&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&repo_id=126450947&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dbuild_Zlib.v1.2.11.jl&response-content-?type=application%2Foctet-stream [following]
│ --2020-06-14 20:26:43--  https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/126450947/3549c780-3c62-11e9-9144-67fac571e02a?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20200614%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200614T182643Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=fe638ea82a12f0d962d80996378f917f7d5ccd387197248e5a7ee9239f11f6d3&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&repo_id=126450947&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dbuild_Zlib.v1.2.11.jl&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
│ Resolving github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com (github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
│ wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com’
└ @ Pkg.Operations /build/julia-wJr69F/julia-1.0.3+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1097
```

Consistent with the feedback from the REPL, I then proceeded to run the following:

```
Pkg.build("LibCURL")
```

and got back from Julia the following:

```
Error: Error building `LibCURL`: 
│ ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: products not defined
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] getproperty(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./sysimg.jl:13
│  [2] top-level scope at /home/jerzy/.julia/packages/LibCURL/lWJxD/deps/build.jl:26
│  [3] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
│  [5] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [6] include(::String) at ./client.jl:392
│  [7] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at /home/jerzy/.julia/packages/LibCURL/lWJxD/deps/build.jl:14
└ @ Pkg.Operations /build/julia-wJr69F/julia-1.0.3+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1097
```

I then restarted the REPL, to no avail.
Is there a fix to this issue?
My environment: Debian 10 LTS. I intend to send emails from my desktop using third-party SMTP servers. Are there perchance any other packages that would do this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the network connection failed in the middle of installation process of `LibCURL`.

Try removing the package and adding again:

```
using Pkg
pkg"rm SMTPClient"
pkg"rm LibCURL" 
pkg"add LibCURL"
```

Another possible reasons could be no disk space/quota left or some problem with writing rights to your `.julia` location.